# mySQL Best Idea for Looping

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mySQL table that holds a record for each client.  In this structure it lists who their boss is and determines by their bosses score if they stay at the same level or if they move up because their boss number didn't reach a certain level.  Looping through once is easy, but I need to determine if a persons boss didn't qualify then to look at their bosses boss and check and so on and move people accordingly.

```
ID, Level, BossID, Sales, AdjustedLevel

3333, 4, 2222, 79, NULL

1111, 3, 7777, 125, NULL

2222, 6, 9999, 320, NULL

4444, 5, 3333, 200, NULL

5555, 5, 3333, 50, NULL

6666, 6, 5555, 100, NULL
```

I need to update AdjustedLevel that will move each employee up a level if their boss doesn't sell over 100.  But up 2 levels if their boss doesn't sell over 100 and their bosses boss doesn't sell over 100 either, etc. etc.  I need this to work for as many as 20 levels of employees in this structure with level 1 being the lowest someone could drop.

ID 3333 would stay at level 4 for AdjustedLevel because their boss (2222) qualified with $320 sales.
ID 4444's AdjustedLevel would drop 1 because their boss (3333) didn't qualify.
ID 6666's AdjustedLevel would drop 1 because 5555 didn't qualify, but then drop another because their bosses boss 3333 didn't qualify, but check their boss (2222) and they did, so they stop at Level 4.

I want to find the best way to have my Stored Proc calculate everyone's adjustedLevel the most effecient way and write one UPDATE to the table with all the adjusted level's.

Ideas?

Thanks!!

Comment: What version of MySQL do you use?

Comment: For *N* levels you should need *N* queries, maximum, with the proper grouping.

Comment: Server version: 8.0.22 MySQL

Comment: My initial thought was to loop starting at level 2 and update all those people to level 1 where their boss didn't qualify, then move to level 3 and loop through and use their bosses adjusted level number to determine if it should be equal to or 1 higher than their bosses, and continue until all levels were exhausted.